# mvc security and access control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I want to know how security and access control is handled within MVC.

My case is, let's say I am managing an website where user can post a note that is not accessible by other user unless permission is given to do so.
My database is currently structured as below.

User

- User ID int

Note

- User ID int

User_Owns_Note

- User ID int
- Note ID int

User_Owns_Note table has data of

- 1, 3
- 3, 1
- 3, 2
- 1, 1
- 2, 5

Let's then say I have below URL and which will only be accessible by users with UserID 3 and 1 according to the owns note table.

- /Note/Edit/1

What is the best practice to implement this kind of restriction ?

I can simply look up the table in the Edit Action and redirect to other page if user doesn't have access. But my problem is then when I implement new Delete action, or whatever actions in the future, I need to place the same code at the start of each action. Is this only way to implement this ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Iprincipal Identity could be fine. you can check tihs source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9dd5fx0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just put the validation code into a private helper method and call that method from each of your controller methods.

Comment: Hi Stephen Could you please give me an example ?

Comment: is Using Identity with Role good practice for this case? How we assign this type of access using roles ?